# 2 dimensional scrolling chart for Epg or some schedule in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout, epg

I will share my diagram for the screen first.

[Diagram of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W2sI.jpg)

Each cell Pij represents a program scheduled for the channel Ci in the leftmost channel column which should scroll vertically with the grid. It also corresponds to timeline, horizontally scrolling list of timings (the topmost row). Cell width should be proportional to program's duration.

**Ways i thought about**

1) [Trouble synchronizing scrolling in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKWc5.jpg)

There are some other variations I attempted, but nothing worked.
There are similar question on stackoverflow but i have't found the solution.
links of those question :

[Scroll multiple recyclerviews on one recyclerview scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812674/scroll-multiple-horizontal-recyclerview-together/)

and

[How to show EPG in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760025/how-to-show-epg-in-android/)

I am not very confident about the method that I should develop for this problem.

I also thought about using **webView and Html**, looking into it.

So, please have a look and give me your important suggestion and guidance.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [waq aslam ](stackoverflow.com/users/966550/waqaslam) hi ,you posted a question ([your question],(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812674/scroll-multiple-horizontal-recyclerview-together?lq=1)  had similar goal .Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to add textviews in horizontal rows. The length of the textview depends on the duration of the program. I have hosted a sample project on Github. Feel free to clone.
https://github.com/xardox69/android_EPG